# Disabled IPV6 but still showing in netstat

Tags: ubuntu, security, ipv6

newbie here, for security best practice I want to disable IPV6 (not to deal with IPV6 firewall settings). I use Hetzner root server Ubuntu 12.04 . 
/etc/sysctl.conf file already have a setting from default Hetzner install and I added only last 3 row

```
# ipv6 settings (no autoconfiguration) This part come from defau install 
net.ipv6.conf.default.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_dad=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_defrtr=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_rtr_pref=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra_pinfo=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_source_route=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_redirects=0
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.autoconf=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_dad=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_defrtr=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_rtr_pref=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_pinfo=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects=0
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=0
# I have added following myself
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

When I do netstat -tulpn still get udp6 and tcp6 results

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1222/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1019/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1198/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      862/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1198/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      862/sshd
udp        0      0 1XX.XX.XXX.XXX:123       0.0.0.0:*                           1241/ntpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           1241/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           1241/ntpd
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                1241/ntpd
```

Do upd6 and tcp6 means still I have IPV6 enabled? Should I delete default Hetzner IPV6 settings?
Thanks for all.
Edit: I already did sysctl -p and I also tried rebooting.

Comment: Disabling IPv6 is exactly the opposite of a best practice. And firewalling it is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in as root or superuser.
In the /etc/modprobe/aliases file, change this line :

alias net-pf-10 ipv6

To:

alias net-pf-10 off

Save the file and reboot the system.

Comment: Thans for your answer but Ubuntu 12.04 does not have  /etc/modprobe/aliases file.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu perhaps see [this question](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebBrowsingSlowIPv6IPv4) on the Ubuntu community site which suggests:

1. Boot the Ubuntu 8.04 LTS Server Edition Installation CD
2. Select your language
3. Highlight "Install Ubuntu Server" (DO NOT press "Enter")
4. Press the function key "F6"
5. Add "ipv6.blacklist=yes" to the kernel parameters (The line should read "... -- ipv6.blacklist=yes" afterwards)
6. Press the "Enter" key to continue with the installation as usual

The file "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.local" with content shown below will be created:

```
# Local module settings
# Created by the Debian installer
blacklist ipv6
```